# how to pass req.params in a {mergeparams} for a post request express

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I am trying to make a post request in a nested route but i keep getting 404 on postman.

app.js to handle my routes

```
app.use("/channel", controllers.channelController);
app.use("/channelentry", controllers.channelEntryController);
```

channelcontroller

```
const Express = require('express');
const router = Express.Router();
const channelEntry = require('./channelentrycontroller')

router.use('/:channelId', channelEntry)
```

channelEntryController

```
const Express = require('express');
const channelEntry = Express.Router({mergeParams: true});


channelEntry.get("/", async (req, res) => {
const channelId = req.params.channelId
try {
    const messages = await models.ChannelEntryModel.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: models.ChannelModel,
            where: { channelId: channelId }
        }],
    });

    res.status(200).json({messages})
} catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({error: err})
}
});


channelEntry.post("/create", validateJWT, async (req, res) => {
const {entry} = req.body.channelentry
const channelId = req.params.channelId
const channelMessage = {
    entry,
    userId: req.user.userId,
    channelId: channelId
}
try {
    const currentChannelId =  await models.ChannelModel.findOne({
        where: {
            channelId: channelId
        }
    })
    const newChannel = await models.ChannelEntryModel.create(channelMessage, currentChannelId);
    res.status(200).json(newChannel)
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).json({error: err})
}
})
```

my get request works but sends an empty array because i have no entrys.

Comment: before i implemented mergeparams, my endpoint was channelEntry.post("/create/:channelId"... this was working previously before i wanted to use nested routes.

Comment: actually my get request does not work. i am inputting wrong parameters in postman and im still getting 200 response

Answer (score 0):

I ended up answering my own question.

I commented out:

```
app.use("/channelentry", controllers.channelEntryController);
```

I guess it was conflicting with my other route.